# Check for symbol is a [pointer to] member function/field in D

Tags: templates, d

In C++ we can easily detect that given type is a pointer to member function/field:

```cpp
template< class T >
struct is_member_pointer : std::false_type {};

template< class T, class U >
struct is_member_pointer<T U::*> : std::true_type {};
```

There are no such syntax in D (I mean `T U::*`). Moreover, free functions and methods have the same type:

```d
void func();

struct S
{
    int x;
    void func() {}
}

static assert(is(typeof(func) == typeof(S.func)));
```

So, my question is: can we write in D a template which is analogous to C++-version?

```d
template is_member_of(alias M)
{
    alias T = /**/;
}

static assert(is(is_member_of!(S.func) == S));
static assert(is(is_member_of!func == void));
static assert(is(is_member_of!(S.x) == S));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try taking the address of the function via the `init` object instead:

```
static assert(is(typeof(&func) == typeof(&S.init.func)));
```

Will give:

```
ooo.d(9): Error: static assert:  is(void function() == void delegate()) is false
```

The member function (unless it is static, but then it isn't *really* a member function) will be typed `delegate` because it requires a `this` object, whereas the other one will be typed `function`.

That will work for the function, and you can do something similar with the variable (tip: `static assert:  is(typeof(& x)) is false`, but `static assert(is(typeof(&S.init.x));` passes - note the .init) if you are curious about if it is an actual member, with a runtime `this` requirement (that is, not `static`).

I'll leave turning this information into a template check as an exercise to the reader (tip though: `is(typeof(something) == delegate)` is a thing in the language...)

But, if you want to just know if there's a parent type on the symbol, there's a different way: just ask the compiler if there's a parent! OK, I confess the code is slightly longer to get the `void` response your static asserts were looking for, but not much:

```
// identity template to hack around parser limitations
// this is common when using the __traits stuff, alas.
alias I(alias T) = T;

template is_member_of(alias M) {
        // if it has a parent, return it, otherwise, return void
        static if(is(I!(__traits(parent, M))))
                alias is_member_of = I!(__traits(parent, M));
        else
                alias is_member_of = void;
}
```

You might furthermore check if the parent is certain things like struct or class, but really, if it exists at all it is probably what you're looking for.